# Awful flickering when hovering over a sub menu during transition

Tags: jquery, menu

I've got a slight problem when you hover over a sub menu dropping down while it's in transition...it flickers terribly, really bad... I tried adding .stop but it didn't help, naturally many users will hover down whilst the effect is in transition.... so hopefully there's a way to stop this, I've built the following...

http://jsfiddle.net/awxgY/3/

```
// menu hover functionality
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('nav li,#mini-menu li').hover(
    function () {
  //show its submenu
  $('.sub-nav', this).slideDown(400).stop;
  $('.mini-nav', this).fadeIn(300).stop;
}, 
function () {
  //hide its submenu
  $('.sub-nav,.mini-nav', this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(300);           
}
  );    

// preserves nav hover state
  $("nav ul li .sub-nav").each(function(i){
$(this).hover(function(){
  $(this).parent().find("a").slice(0,1).addClass("navactive");
},function(){
  $(this).parent().find("a").slice(0,1).removeClass("navactive");
});
 });
});
```

If you hover over Link 4 > And enter the sub menu whilst it's coming in you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Swipe diagonally downwards (quickly) across link 4 into the sub menu, you'll get bad flicker...

Comment: Looks fine to me too. I tried it both on Firefox 21.0 and Chromium 25.0 on Ubuntu.

Comment: OK, i've edited so you should get the error as well... Good confident swipe towards he sub menu please and hold it there

http://jsfiddle.net/awxgY/3/

Comment: firstly, the `.stop()` requires the paranthesis, since it is a function. Secondly, the `.stop()` function should be called BEFORE any animations.. not after... ` $('.sub-nav', this).stop().slideDown(400);` - not sure if this solves the problem b/c Im not really seeing it. Putting stop after the animation causes the current one to stop, which is not what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/awxgY/5/

Comment: Hi, > I've tried that but get flicker still when  mousing over the fade in or fade out transition of the sub nav > i've updated the jsfiddle to hopefully replicate it better for you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work OK - http://jsfiddle.net/awxgY/6/

Firstly, the .stop() requires the paranthesis, since it is a function. Secondly, the .stop() function should be called BEFORE any animations.. not after... `$('.sub-nav', this).stop().slideDown(400);` - not sure if this solves the problem b/c Im not really seeing it. Putting stop after the animation causes the current one to stop, which is not what you want.

I also added a `stopPropagation()` call to eliminate any "rolling over" of the hover commands.

Comment: seems much better, not super perfect, but definitely improves upon it, appreciate you taking the time with this :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the white space between menu and submenu. http://jsfiddle.net/ecTLz/

```
.sub-nav { display: none; position: absolute; overflow: auto; top: 60px; width: 100%; z-index: 500; left: 0; padding: 2em 0;background:#000}
```